# Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Someone tell where there is a bug?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE catalog_get_departments_list()
BEGIN
SELECT department_id, name FROM department ORDER BY department_id;
END$$
```

And this error crashes:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Comment: "Someone tell where there is a bug?"  It's only a bug if MySQL is not doing what it says it will do.  A syntax error is not a bug, it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove dollars at the end:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE catalog_get_departments_list()
BEGIN
SELECT department_id, name FROM department ORDER BY department_id;
END
```

or set delimiter

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE catalog_get_departments_list()
BEGIN
SELECT department_id, name FROM department ORDER BY department_id;
END$$
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but did not help.

Comment: @user1362765: Saying merely "did not help" without any explanation (like whether the issue remained the same or, perhaps, changed to a different one) isn't very helpful either. @Marco: I am not really a MySQL person, so my question may sound silly: is resetting the statement delimiter character to the default `;` *always* necessary after a subroutine definition (in case you changed it previously, of course)? In other words, I'm wondering whether you must issue `DELIMITER ;` just after `END$$` or not (regardless of whether any more statements would follow).

Comment: @AndriyM: according to MySql manual no (see some example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)), it's not necessary. But you'r completely right: OP did not tell us anything regarding why it did not help... so we can't really help him!!

Answer (score 0):

One more variant for your MySQL client -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE catalog_get_departments_list()
SELECT department_id, name FROM department ORDER BY department_id;
```